Boot problem: black screen after grub menu
When i switch on the pc I have automatically the Grub menu. If i click on "Advanced options" I can use Linux 6.4.0-28 and 6.4.0.34. if i boot with the first one it doesn't give me problems, the second one locks on "Loading initial ramdisk".
Worst than this, if I just go on "Ubuntu" in the grub menu, it gives me a black screen without anything.
I read something online and I supposed it was a kernel problem, so I tried to set the 6.5.0-28 as default editing /etc/default/grub and changing GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT=saved, then I added GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true and updated Grub with sudo update-grub
When i rebooted i went to "advanced options", run -28 and rebooted again trying running directly "Ubuntu", but it still gives me the black screen.
Where is the problem? what should I do?
Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer swift 3 314-511-74UC. I tested the other kernels just because it was the first thing easily switchable, and apparently with one it work better than the other, but both give me a different result from the standard boot.

I'd try the recovery mode to, hopefully, get more info about the problem.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop?); but have do mention a testing 6.4 kernel??  What Ubuntu product are you using? and on what device?  and why the testing kernels?

@mikewhatever what do you mean?

@guiverc I edited, with more infos, I didn't tried with the 6.4
